# Динамическое добавление grains в saltstack

Tags: linux, jinja2, saltstack

Имеется 3 sls файла.
В первом - init.sls прописано:

```
include:
  - logick.grains
  - logick.install
```

Во втором grains.sls прописано:

```
set_customer_grain:
  cmd.run:
    - name: salt-call grains.set antivirus ['lightagent']

update_pillar_grains:
  cmd.run:
    - name: salt-call saltutil.refresh_pillar
```

В третьем файле прописаны различные формулы.
Проблема заключается в том, что logick.install выполнится, если на вм будет прописан grains 'antivirus'. Но если добавлять этот грейнс через logick.grains, то state.apply упадет на компиляции, ибо logick.install не увидит этот grains.

Помогите, пожайлуста, сделать так, чтобы компиляция прошла успешно.